# boto3 s3 copyObject error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, boto3

I'm trying to copy a file from 1 bucket to another prefix in the same bucket using lambda & boto3 however I keep getting an error:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject
>   operation.

or

> An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

depending on which copy method I use.

The lambda function has a role assigned to it, which I think gives it all the permissions it requires:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:HeadObject",
            "s3:ListObjects"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    },
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/folderA/folderB/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/folderC/folderD/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/folderE/folderF/*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
]
}
```

The lambda function is:

```
#connect to s3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

dirs = {
    "folderA/folderB": "folderC/folderD"        
}    

key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
etag = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['eTag'], encoding='utf-8')    
bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']

filePathName = key.split("/")
sourceDir = filePathName[0] + "/" + filePathName[1]
fileName = filePathName[2]

sourceKey = sourceDir + "/" + fileName
source = {'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': sourceKey}
destination = dirs[sourceDir] + "/" + fileName

##########
# This option comes up with the An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation. Error
###########
s3.Object(bucket, destination).copy_from(CopySource=source)

###########
## This option comes up with the An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden error
###########
s3.meta.client.copy(source, bucket, destination)
```

EDIT:
forgot to mention, it works fine if I change the role to

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
```

Comment: Looks reasonable at a glance. Have you given the Lambda function s3:* permission to arn:aws:s3:::* temporarily to verify that this works when fully-permissioned? Just to rule out something silly, like the wrong bucket name? Also, log the various values like bucket and source to double-check them.

Comment: yes sorry forgot to mention, if I give it S3:* to the specific bucket (not all buckets), it works fine but when I lock it down as per the above, it no longer works and throws up these errors

Comment: I think the challenge here is that you are using high-level SDK calls (copy_from and client copy) and you don't know what S3 API calls they actually make under the covers (and boto3 doesn't explicitly document them). I am assuming that the list of actions that you have specified is insufficient. You might be able to discover the full list from CloudTrail or by reading the boto3 code. Perhaps GetBucketLoction, PutObjectTagging and the object ACL actions, for example. You could try to work out which, or add Get* and Put* for starters.

Comment: tried that already. Gave it s3:Get* and s3:Put* on the bucket and s3:* on the folders with no luck

Comment: You should use arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name rather than arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/ when referring to a bucket.

Comment: true, fixed that since posting on here but that was not it unfortunately

Comment: OK, well you know a set of permissions that is insufficient and a set that is sufficient, so the minimal set lies somewhere between the two. There's no documentation that I'm aware of that helps here so I suggest a binary chop approach.

Comment: what more can I give other than s3:Put*, s3:Get* and s3:List* ?

Comment: HeadBucket, for example. AWS documents the list of S3 actions (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_s3.html).

Answer (score 9):

I was running into a similar problem. The solution: `source` in `CopySource=source` had to be a full path from the bucket root to the actual file instead of a dictionary of bucket name and key. So I think your code may have to be:

`s3.Object(bucket, destination).copy_from(CopySource=bucket + sourceDir)`

Comment: Can you please tell me how does this work? I don't see anywhere you are specifying destination credentials and source credentials.

Comment: this is a modification of the OP's code. So you could see the definitions of those variables in the original post.

Comment: the dictionary of bucket name and key is actually the recommended way of specifying CopySource.
Ref: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.copy_from

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but maybe for someone will be helpful:

```py
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'my_perfect_bucket',
    'Key': 'media/old_path/glory.jpg'
}

s3.Object('my_perfect_bucket','media/new_path/glory.jpg').copy_from(CopySource=copy_source)
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that many of the other solutions here are not particularly "turn-key", especially in terms of handling large buckets or working in an environment where aws-cli is not available.

This one doesn't rely on aws-cli and uses the boto3 paginators to handle large buckets.

```py
import boto3

def recursive_s3_cp(source_bucket, source_bucket_path, dest_bucket, dest_bucket_path):
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
    paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
            Bucket=source_bucket,
            Prefix=source_bucket_path,
            Delimiter="/"
            )
    result = response_iterator.build_full_result()
    # Skip first item as it's a reference to the prefix directory
    for bucket_object in result['Contents'][1:]:
        new_path = bucket_object['Key'].replace(source_bucket_path, dest_bucket_path)
        response = s3_client.copy_object(
                # Tons of other parameters you can pass here if you need them
                Bucket=dest_bucket,
                CopySource={
                    'Bucket': source_bucket,
                    'Key': bucket_object['Key']
                    },
                Key=new_path,
                )
        if not response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
            raise Exception('s3 copy failed with response: ', response)
```